# Need to override block.tpl.php in a module

Tags: 7, theming

I need to define a block--custom.tpl.php file in a custom module and have that override the theme block.tpl.php.

Here is where I have ended up and it's not working.

Tell Drupal to look in my module:

```
function MODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['block']['theme paths'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE');
  $theme_registry['block']['theme paths'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE') . '/theme';
}
```

In `hook_preprocess_HOOK()` suggest a new theme file:

```
function MODULE_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $block = $variables['block'];

  if ($block->CONDITION) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block__MODULE';
  }
}
```

Now, I've created the file in the module's theme/ folder and called it block--MODULE.tpl.php.

I've turned on theme debugging in the settings file by un-commenting out `$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;`

Caches have been cleared multiple times. When I load the page I see in the debug comments:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- CALL: theme('block') -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * block--MODULE.tpl.php
   * block--block--6.tpl.php
   * block--block.tpl.php
   * block--content.tpl.php
   x block.tpl.php
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'sites/all/themes/THEME/templates/block.tpl.php' -->
```

And as you can see from the debug it is using the theme template file.

How do I get Drupal to select the proper theme file?

Comment: There are two different ways to do it suggested here => https://www.drupal.org/node/715160, the first one applies to your case.

Comment: These all talk about nodes and as you can tell from my example, I am using this method (sort of). I need a block specific method.

Comment: I also don't want to override the block theme registry for all blocks, only those that meet a specific condition.

Comment: Right you are :-) Let me have a deeper look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function rals_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $theme = array();
  $theme['block__custom'] = array(
    'render element' => 'content',
    'template' => 'block--custom',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'rals'),
   );
  return $theme;
}


/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function rals_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $block = $variables['block'];
  if ($block->bid == 3) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block__custom';
  }
}
```

and succesfully uses my module-folder-located template file for rendering the block with bid == 3.

Good luck in any case!